# How to further simplify this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given that $V$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal rectangular $m\times n$ matrix, $U$ is an $m\times m$ matrix, $b$ is an $m\times 1$ matrix and $\lambda$ is a positive number, how do you further simplify the given equation

$$x = (V^T)^{-1}(\Sigma^T\Sigma+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^TU^Tb$$

Comment: A diagonal matrix is square by definition. What do you mean by $\Sigma$ is a diagonal $m \times n$ matrix?

Comment: Diagonal matrices do not have to be square. Rectangular matrices, by definition are m-by-n matrices with only the entries of the form $d_{i,i}$ possibly non-zero. For more just check the wikipedia page: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix)

Comment: If $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, note that $(V^T)^{-1} = V$.  Outside of that, there isn't much "simplification" to be made here.